# why show this error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: laravel

have problem with forech?

the code to send emails is correct, I would just like to call the search result data from the .email column, because the line will always have a result, is there another way to do this?

(1/1) ErrorException
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
$update = encomendas::
        join('encomendas_pagamentos', 'encomendas.id', '=', 'encomendas_pagamentos.id_encomenda')
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.entidade', $ENTIDADE)
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.referencia', $REFERENCIA)
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.valor', $VALOR)
        ->update(['encomendas.estado' => 2]);


    //$email=$update->email;


    foreach ($update as $update) {

        Mail::send('emails.email-contacto', ['entidade' => $ENTIDADE,
        ], function ($messagem) use ($update) {

            $messagem->from('xxx@xxxxx.pt', 'xxxxxx');

            $messagem->to($update->email)->subject('xxxxx.pt notificação de pagamento');

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the result of the update() operation in your query returns how many rows were successfully updated. I don't know of any ways where you can update a set of records, and retrieve a collection of the results in the same command.

You can solve your issue like so:

```
encomendas::join('encomendas_pagamentos', 'encomendas.id', '=', 'encomendas_pagamentos.id_encomenda')
          ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.entidade', $ENTIDADE)
          ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.referencia', $REFERENCIA)
          ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.valor', $VALOR)
          ->update(['encomendas.estado' => 2]);

$update = encomendas::
        join('encomendas_pagamentos', 'encomendas.id', '=', 'encomendas_pagamentos.id_encomenda')
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.entidade', $ENTIDADE)
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.referencia', $REFERENCIA)
        ->where('encomendas_pagamentos.valor', $VALOR)
        ->select('encomendas.*')
        ->get();
```